# Clarification on how argument data for a vertex function using MTLVertexDescriptor and the [[attribute(n)]] attribute is located

Tags: swift, metal

Consider the following MSL:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct VertexIn {
    float3 position     [[attribute(0)]];
    float3 normal       [[attribute(1)]];
    float3 color        [[attribute(2)]];
};

// Void just for demonstration
vertex void vertexFunc(const VertexIn vIn [[stage_in]]) {}
```

The concept of `MTLBuffer` objects and `MTLVertexDescriptor` objects is clear: the latter describes how data for a Metal struct (`VertexIn` in this case) is distributed among different `MTLBuffer` objects. Then, adding the `[[stage_in]]` attribute to the argument into a vertex function with the struct's type, an instance is created with the struct's members matched to the data.

I have one question: does `[[stage_in]]` automatically offset the buffer by the total size of all attributes using a particular buffer (`totalSize`) by `totalSize * [[vertex_id]]` within each `MTLBuffer` before binding the struct's members to the data with the attribute layout information? I figure this must happen, but I haven't yet found anything mentioning if/how/when this occurs with `[[stage_in]]`.

For example, if we used

```
let descriptor = MTLVertexDescriptor()

// Position
descriptor.attributes[0].format = .float3
descriptor.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0
descriptor.attributes[0].offset = 0

// Normal
descriptor.attributes[1].format = .float3
descriptor.attributes[1].bufferIndex = 0
descriptor.attributes[1].offset = MemoryLayout<vector_float3>.stride

// Color
descriptor.attributes[2].format = .float3
descriptor.attributes[2].bufferIndex = 1
descriptor.attributes[2].offset = 0

descriptor.layouts[0].stride = 2 * MemoryLayout<vector_float3>.stride
descriptor.layouts[1].stride = MemoryLayout<vector_float3>.stride
```

and set two buffers, one with the interleaved position and normal data and the other with color data, would the vertex shader receive the nth vertex's data at `(buffer0Start) + n * (sizeof(float3) + sizeof(float3))` in buffer 0 and `(buffer1Start) + n * (sizeof(float3))` in buffer 1 with `[[stage_in]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is the case. Section 5.2.4, page 87 of Apple's "Metal Shading Language Specification" Version 2.2 reads

> A vertex function can read per-vertex inputs by indexing into
> buffer(s) passed as arguments to the vertex function using the vertex
> and instance IDs. To assemble per-vertex inputs and pass them as
> arguments to a vertex function, declare the inputs with the
> `[[stage_in]]` attribute.